# DataContext in view doesn't change although Controller implements INotifyPropertyChanged WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a view where I implement a UserControl. 
This UserControl makes changes to the ObservableCollection in my Controller.
The Listbox is binded to this ObservableCollection.

The changes just won't be updated in my view. 
Actually this should happen automatically? Or am I wrong?
Is there anything I'm missing out here?

```
<ListView x:Name="ListViewEmployees" ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeDetails, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="7" Grid.RowSpan="5">
```

What do I need to add here?

Using .Net 4.5

Code-Behind from view where Datacontext gets set:

```
 var context = new PlanningController();
            DataContext = context;
            context.employeePlanning(date);
```

PlanningController:

```
     public class PlanningController : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<EmployeeDetails> _employeeDetails = null;

    private const string seperator = "; ";

    public void employeePlanning()
    {
        EmployeeDetails = new ObservableCollection<EmployeeDetails>();
        try
        {
            using (var db = new Context())
            {
                var employee = (db.Qualification.Join(db.Employee, qual => qual.QualificationId,
                    emp => emp.QualificationId, (qual, emp) => new EmployeeDetails
                    {
                        EmployeeId = emp.EmployeeId,
                        ShortForm = emp.ShortNameForm,
                        WorkingHours = emp.WorkingHours,
                        Degree = qual.Qualification
                    }));

                foreach (var emp in employee)
                {
                    EmployeeDetails.Add(emp);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<EmployeeDetails> EmployeeDetails
    {
        get
        {
            return _employeeDetails;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_employeeDetails == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _employeeDetails = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string _text;

    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }

        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                return;

            _text = value;
            employeeResourceControlChanged();
        }
    }

    private Brush _brush;
    public Brush Brush
    {
        get { return _brush; }
        set
        {
            _brush = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));

        }
    }



    private void employeeResourceControlChanged()
    {
        var enteredText = _text;
        var delimiters = new char[] { ';', ' ' };

        if (enteredText.Length < 3)
            return;

        if (enteredText.Length >= 3)
        {
            var parts = enteredText.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            var exists = checkIfEmployeeExists(parts);
            if (exists.Count == 1)
            {
                var text = exists[0] + seperator;
                if (exists[0] == parts[parts.Length - 1])
                {
                    _text = text;
                    _brush = Brushes.White;
                }
                else
                {
                    _text = text + parts[parts.Length - 1];
                    _brush = Brushes.DarkRed;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (exists.Count == 0)
                    return;

                var text = String.Join(seperator, exists);
                if (exists[exists.Count - 1] == parts[parts.Length - 1])
                {
                    _text = text + seperator;
                    _brush = Brushes.White;
                }
                else
                {
                    var npart = parts.Distinct().ToList();
                    if (npart.Count() != parts.Count())
                    {
                        _text = text + seperator;
                        _brush = Brushes.White;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _text = text + seperator + parts[parts.Length - 1];
                        _brush = Brushes.DarkRed;
                        //TextBoxEmployeeDetails.BorderThickness = new Thickness(2);
                    }
                }
            }

            //TextBoxEmployeeDetails.SelectionStart = TextBoxEmployeeDetails.Text.Length + 1;
        }
    }

    private List<String> checkIfEmployeeExists(string[] empShort)
    {
        var list = new List<string>();
        for (int index = 0; index < EmployeeDetails.Count; index++)
        {
            var employee = _employeeDetails[index];
            for (int i = 0; i < empShort.Length; i++)
            {
                var shortForm = empShort[i];
                if (employee.ShortForm.Contains(shortForm) && shortForm.Length == 3)
                {
                    employee.WorkingHours -= 8;
                    list.Add(employee.ShortForm);
                }
            }
        }

        return list.Distinct().ToList();
    }
```

EmployeeDetails class

```
public class EmployeeDetails
{
    public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string ShortForm { get; set; }
    public string Degree { get; set; }
    public double WorkingHours { get; set; }
}
```

UserControl:

```
public partial class AddEmployeeToShiftControl : UserControl
{
    public AddEmployeeToShiftControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        TextBoxEmployeeDetails.TextChanged += TextBoxEmployeeDetails_TextChanged;

    }

    void TextBoxEmployeeDetails_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBoxEmployeeDetails.SelectionStart = TextBoxEmployeeDetails.Text.Length + 1;
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BrushProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Brush", typeof(string), typeof(AddEmployeeToShiftControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

    public string Brush
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(BrushProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BrushProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Text", typeof(string), typeof(AddEmployeeToShiftControl), null);

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(TextProperty, value);

        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectionStartProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "SelectionStart", typeof(int), typeof(AddEmployeeToShiftControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(int)));

    public int SelectionStart
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(SelectionStartProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectionStartProperty, value); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void SetValueDp(DependencyProperty property, object value,
    [CallerMemberName] String p = null)
    {
        SetValue(property, value);
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
    }
```

Comment: You cannot clear an observable collection otherwise you have to rebind it manually. you need to add and remove item from it manually 1 by 1.

Comment: `Binding Employee`, hmmm, perhaps a typo?

Comment: When you post question you should put all the relevant code in this case your viewModel, UserControl or code behind etc...

Comment: What .NET version are you using ?

Comment: Setting `Mode=TwoWay` on an `ItemsSource` property is redundant... how do you expect that it can update the data source?. @JenishRabadiya is correct... you should show all of your *relevant* code, as adding items to an `ObservableCollection` *should* be displayed in the UI but we can't diagnose your problem without seeing your code.

Comment: As soon as I enter the shortform from the employee the workinghours will be substracted. the left over workinghours should be shown in the listbox.This is working. So the Observablecollection contains the new workinghours. This is just not beeing displayed in my view.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems you mixed up two properties with `Employee` and `EmployeeDetails`, and assign the wrong instance var inside your `Employee` Property: `_employeeDetails = value;`

Comment: @jonny it's a bit confusing to name the collection exactly as the class...

Comment: Actually, it doesn't even compile :P But I managed to get a sample working, and the ListView is indeed updated... The error must be somewhere else in code.

Comment: this is weird. with actual code above? did you implement INPC in EmployeeDetails? as said below or?

Comment: No, there's no need, since you're not modifying their values after adding them to the collection. The only important facts here are: the view and control are correclty bound and their DataContext correctly set; the collection is Observable and public; and you fire the PropertyChanged event when the collection value is set... And you seem to do all that.

Comment: The only thing I find confusing is your implementation of RaisePropertyChanged... Are you sure the `[CallerMemberName]` is working? I had to change that bit, but it did work removing it altogether, too (surprisingly)

Comment: exactly. and thats why its weird that weird that the view doesnt get updated.

Comment: yes thats working... if I type "EmployeeDetails" resharper tells me redundant code. Even if I add the string. nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

Your Employee class, i  mean the T in ObservableCollection has INPC implemented on its public properties? And your RaisePropertyChanged() is strange, can you show us the code for that?

Usually such an observable is implemented like this:

```
    private ObservableCollection<Employee> _items = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();

    public ObservableCollection<Employee> items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set
        {
            _items = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("items"));
        }
    }
```

This thing right here on the collection assures that if you change the pointer of items to another collection your view will remain in sync. Otherwise you will hold a reference to the old collection.

But in order to change the properties of each Employee, you need to implement INPC interface on its properties too. So, be careful with the implementation there.

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
```

This is the thing with the delegate trick included.

```
PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("items"));
```

And this is the trigger, include the name of the property there.This is a must!

In my situation the binding in XAML should be defined like follows:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding items}">
```

assuming that your DataContext is set correctly either from XAML or from code, this should work.

Comment: the callermembervalue does this job here.

Comment: @jonny I think you changed the details a bit right there, i only saw Employee class in many places.

Comment: ya i just changed this to make it more understandable.

Comment: @jonny your EmployeeDetails  needs INPC implemented.

Comment: did so. but still nothing happens